# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests.adapters' when using pyfcm

Tags: python, django, python-requests, pyfcm

I'm trying to use `pyfcm` library in my django project , by adding it to `requiements.txt` but I noticed that it is getting an error that mainly comes because of trying to import from `requests` library .. here is the error :

```
rolla_django       |     from pyfcm import FCMNotification
rolla_django       |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pyfcm/__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
rolla_django       |     from .fcm import FCMNotification
rolla_django       |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pyfcm/fcm.py", line 1, in <module>
rolla_django       |     from .baseapi import BaseAPI
rolla_django       |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pyfcm/baseapi.py", line 6, in <module>
rolla_django       |     from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter
rolla_django       | ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests.adapters'
```

and here is my `requirements.txt`

```
Django~=4.1.1
djangorestframework~=3.13.1
django-extensions
pymysql~=1.0.2
requests
tzdata
psycopg2-binary
django-crontab
pyfcm
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try these things

1. Update pyfcm to the latest version (1.5.4)
2. Update requests to the latest version (2.28.1)

Comment: It is not working too :( still the same error after changing my requirements.txt to match those versions

Comment: Django uses its own copy of python which could cause conflicts with your system Python. can you check in your Django project for the correct python version?

Comment: well, I am running it inside a docker container,, using docker-compose so I think it only deals with a single python version